# My code keeps getting a "Name 'breed' is not defined" error

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

My error is:

```
NameError: name 'breed' is not defined
```

but I thought it was defined in the `__init__` function? Any suggestions? This is code from a study guide for an exam, and I'm trying to input it into python 2.7 myself to see the output.

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, breed, owner = "pound"):
        self.owner = owner
        self.breed = breed

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self._owner

    @owner.setter
    def owner(self, value):
        self._owner = value

    @breed.setter
    def breed(self, value):
        self._breed = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "Breed = {}, \tOwner = {}".format(\
                self.breed, self.owner)

d1 = Dog("Beagle")
d2 = Dog("Rottweiler", "James")
d3 = Dog("Poodle")
print "d1: {}".format(d1)
print "d2: {}".format(d2)
print "d3: {}".format(d3)
```

Comment: add getter: `@property
    def breed(self):
        return self._breed`

Comment: You did it right for `owner`, you just have to do the exact same thing for `breed`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have had `@property` for breed as well:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, breed, owner = "pound"):
        self.owner = owner
        self.breed = breed

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self._owner

    @owner.setter
    def owner(self, value):
        self._owner = value

    @property
    def breed(self):
        return self.breed

    @breed.setter
    def breed(self, value):
        self._breed = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "Breed = {}, \tOwner = {}".format(\
                self.breed, self.owner)

d1 = Dog("Beagle")
d2 = Dog("Rottweiler", "James")
d3 = Dog("Poodle")
print "d1: {}".format(d1)
print "d2: {}".format(d2)
print "d3: {}".format(d3)
```